# PHP - A better way to get these values?

Tags: php, regex, substr

```
$image= "some-name-of-my-image-640x480-123.jpg"
```

I need to extract `640x480` and `123`.

What is working for me right now is:

```
list($dirname, $basename, $extension, $filename) = array_values(pathinfo($image));
$new = substr($filename, 0, strrpos($filename, '-')); //some-name-of-my-image-640x480
$post_id = substr($filename, strrpos($filename, '-')+1); //123
$resolution = substr($new, strrpos($new, '-')+1); //640x480
```

Is there something simpler (smarter) to accomplish the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone allergic to regex and with PHP >= 5.2.0:

```
$data = array_slice(explode('-', pathinfo($image, PATHINFO_FILENAME)), -2);
```

In `$data` you'll get:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 640x480
    [1] => 123
)
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use the following regex: `([0-9]+)x([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)`

Or, as suggested in the comments: `(\d+)x(\d+)-(\d+)`

To parse the name:

```
preg_match("/(\d+)x(\d+)-(\d+)/", $file_name, $data);
```

In `$data` you'll get:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 640x480-123
    [1] => 640
    [2] => 480
    [3] => 123
)
```

Comment: `[0-9]` can be replaced with `\d`.